# Kafka offset management in Spark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-kafka

Simple question, I have always read at using Kafka with spark streaming ( structured or not). Using that, you can rely on automatic checkpointing, automatic restart from the last offset/partition and so on.

Now for project requirements, I need to read from a Kafka topic using a spark dataframe job, scheduled in a batch fashion.

What about the Kafka offset per partition handling?
 How can I restart any time the job start, reading only the newest messages?

In poor words:is there any way to have the same features without having necessary a spark streaming job?

Comment: Without Spark Streaming? Kafka Streams has a similar API... but otherwise, just set the starting offset to be latest. Otherwise, the docs show how to specify which offsets to start and end at for each partition

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this issue. We could use some guidance.